# Could not find `Cargo.lock`

Tags: wasm, compile

I'm using [cross](https://github.com/cross-rs/cross) to build my node.

And I got this:

```rs
warning: Could not find `Cargo.lock` for `/root/code/darwinia-network/darwinia-2.0/runtime/pangolin/Cargo.toml`, while searching from `/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/build/pangolin-runtime-7d7c77d31581c197/out`. To fix this, point the `WASM_BUILD_WORKSPACE_HINT` env variable to the directory of the workspace being compiled.
```

How to fix this? How to set the `WASM_BUILD_WORKSPACE_HINT` correctly?

Comment: Have you tried setting it to the workspace directory, as the message suggests? (that would be `/root/code/darwinia-network/darwinia-2.0` in your case).

Comment: Great. You are right.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set it to the workspace directory, as the message suggests. That would be `/root/code/darwinia-network/darwinia-2.0` in your case.